# How to correctly extract binary mask from image opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image as the input and my aim is to extract binary mask which will show only face area. Like pretty simple image segmentation.

My flow:
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZlcv.png) -> [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFyM5.png)

I believe that It could be solved with OpenCV threshold function.

My attempt:

So I tried to implement OpenCV

```
image = cv2.imread('input.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = np.ones((6, 6), dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.blur(gray, (13, 13))
gray = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, 3)
_, thres = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', thres)
```

But It returns pretty dirty [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3czN.png), eyes not flodfilled and some other features are detected.

Comment: Looks like your on the right path to me. Play around with your filter sizes and thresholds some, and this should work. Maybe instead of COLOR_BGR2GRAY to get a unified greyvalue image, use split() to get the RGB channels as single images and see if there's more contrast between face and clothing there.

Comment: you need semantic segmentation. you can't just work on grayscale/brightness values. you need AI if you want to segment the face specifically.